# Can't access tables in public schema in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

I did in pgAdmin tables:[image]

However, from the console, nor from Intelij Idea, I cannot access them.

Gives an error message
"ОШИБКА: отношение "public.Игры" не существует"

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the error say in English? Or add a text version of it to question so I can run it through Google Translate. Are you sure you are connecting to same database in all cases? In `psql` what does `\dt public.*` show?

Comment: Does the IntelliJ encoding match the PostgreSQL client encoding? How do the names look when you select from `information_schema.tables`?

Comment: All. I did it..

Comment: Writes that the relationship "public" was not found

Comment: Please try to rename table names to English.

Comment: And there is no way to fix it, but keep the current names?